# Did you just change the fixed width?

Tags: discussion, design, fixed-width

I noticed SO, SF, SU, and here have a bit wider of a width for their fixed-width layout. Is it just me or did you just change this and why?

Comment: I think I saw a pixel move on the logo! OMG OMG OMG!

Comment: Really? Really?

Comment: How recent was this change? Nothing seems different for me over the last few hours

Comment: After 2pm Eastern. That's the last time I recall seeing a div.article-summary width of 650px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like 80px maybe. That's based on the .article-summary div's on the front page. Used to be 650px, If I remember correctly, and are now 730px. Now at 960px total for the container - a move toward the 960 grid system? :)