# Show sidebar without scrolling at 900ish pixels

Tags: feature-request, design, firefox

**Feature request:** Make the default styling for SE (*et al*) such that you can see the right sidebar without scrolling at 900-ish pixels. (This may just be a rollback?)

It's a useful and reasonably frequent use case* to read SE sites in a browser window that takes up half of your screen and work in the other half, and right now that can be reasonably frustrating.

900 < 960 for browser chrome, taskbars, docks, etc.

---

I'm on a Windows box with a "standard" 1920x1080 monitor, and use WinSplit Revolution to make two windows each take up half my screen.

The last week or two, I've noticed I'm unable to completely see what's on the sidebar next to the questions. I've been using SO for a while, and it seems like I would've noticed this earlier. So on that scant evidence, I wonder if it's a recent change.

[image: This is an image with two browser windows, each taking up half of the screen. They both display horizontal scrollbars. Note: For some reason, Skitch doesn't have a stand-alone installer that works by installing into my Documents folder, and I'm reduced to using MSPaint on my current box. Apologies.]

I can ctrl+[minus] my way out of this, so it's not a horrible dealbreaker, but **did the minimum width for SO grow recently?**

If this is common at 1920px wide, it's probably worth changing for those of us without an iMac or a 4K monitor or what-have-you.

I have ctrl-0'd in my browsers (yes, that's Seamonkey on the right. And there's no Seamonkey tag!) to make sure I'm not doing something completely idiotic. Well, other than using Seamonkey (which I enjoy).

Just to show I did at least minimal search-fu, I found a few close, but not quite, and certainly dated, questions:

- [Can SO have a fluid vs. fixed-width layout?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5070/can-so-have-a-fluid-vs-fixed-width-layout)
- [Did you just change the fixed width?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14112/did-you-just-change-the-fixed-width) (2009! So it's at least a long-running malady)
- [Are there any plans for SE sites to support variable width layout?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137408/are-there-any-plans-for-se-sites-to-support-variable-width-layout?lq=1) (this is actually pretty close, but is, again, asking for a variable width and, more importantly, does suggest the content is 960px where it's now at least 1000px (see `#content` in all.css))

---

#### Why isn't this the same as [Can SO have a fluid vs. fixed-width layout?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5070/can-so-have-a-fluid-vs-fixed-width-layout)

I believe that's asking for a move from fixed to fluid. Here, I don't believe I have any problem with the width of the "answer column", or that it's a fixed size. But there's enough play with the margins, vote count sizes, and sidebars that I believe you could hit closer to 960.

---

<strike>Caveat: I've firebugged nothing in relation to this question.</strike>
**EDIT:** I've now firebugged just enough to know that...

- The sidebar is, indeed, already fixed-width.
- `#content` has a width of `1000px`, so we're obviously shooting for > 960.
- Each question *and* each of their answers have their own `table`, mainly for display. OMGWTFBBQ!1! Don't let the designers near this non-tabular data `table` use. This is why you don't firebug sausage being made.

* I'm guessing.

Comment: I do not want a fixed size sidebar. It is easy enough to scroll to the side to see what is in the sidebar, but most of the time I want all the screen for the questions and answers.

Comment: @Willeke Pretty sure you've already got one. The sidebar's `width` is already `220px`. Look at `#sidebar .sidebar` in `all.css`. But, to be clear, that's *not* what I'm asking for here. I'm asking to tighten up the page so that it shows in 900ish pixels.